Oauth2 Token Request via Excel Script using Fetch Returns Failed to Fetch
I'm trying to create a function in Office Scripts to get an Oauth API token. I have a working token request example in Powershell and attempted to create the same request in Office Script using fetch but am receiving a failed to fetch error in Office scripts.
This PowerShell function successfully retrieves a token:
#requires -Version 3.0
function New-ApiAccessToken
{
    param
    (
        [string]$apiUrl,
        [string]$apiKey,
        [string]$apiSecretKey
    )

    # Specify security protocols
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'

    # Convert password to secure string
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'public' -AsPlainText -Force

    # Define parameters for Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet
    $params = @{
        Credential  =   New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ('public-client', $securePassword)
        Uri         =   '{0}/auth/oauth/token' -f $apiUrl
        Method      =   'POST'
        ContentType =   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        Body        =   'grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}' -f $apiKey, $apiSecretKey
    }
    
    # Request access token
    try {(Invoke-WebRequest @params | ConvertFrom-Json).access_token}
    catch {$_.Exception}
}

# Define parameters
$params = @{
    apiUrl          =   'myurlhere'
    apiKey          =   'thekey'
    apiSecretKey    =   'thesecretkey'
}

# Call New-ApiAccessToken function using defined parameters 
New-ApiAccessToken @params

The below script in Excel/Office Scripts, returns failed to fetch on the fetch line:
async function getToken() {
  let url = 'myurlhere';
  let client_id = 'public-client';
  let client_secret = 'public';
  let username = 'thekey';
  let password = 'thesecretkey';

  let basicAuth: string = base64Encode(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString();
  let bodyParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  bodyParams['grant_type'] = 'password';
  bodyParams['username'] = username;
  bodyParams['password'] = password;

  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + basicAuth
    },
    body: bodyParams
    });

  let token: string = await response.json();
  console.log(token)  
}

When I watch the calls with Fiddler (with Decrypt HTTPS traffic enabled):

PowerShell script shows 2 POST calls; First returns response code 401, Second gets the token with response code 200
Office script shows one OPTIONS call which returns response code 401, There is no second call

How can I update the Office script to successfully get the token?

According to Limitations with external calls from Office Scripts
There is no way to sign in or use OAuth2 type of authentication flows. All keys and credentials have to be hardcoded (or read from another source).
But ... you probably knew that already and want to reimplement the OAuth2 flow.
Have you tried to respond to the HTTP OPTIONS request with a HTTP_OKand header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *?
You should then see the HTTP POST request.

Yes, I'm trying to recreate the OAuth2 flow in Office scripts. I don't have control over the API to update the response. Since my original posting I've identified the Access-Control-Allow-Headers does NOT include OPTIONS. I think that's the cause of the failure and have submitted a support request into the company that does control the API. Thank you for your input.
